# Rearranging column (descending/ascending) with dplyr without a prior vector

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

The following code can rearrange columns if one has prior knowledge of what columns are available, but what if one wants to rearrange the columns by either desc/ascending order? There are a few similar posts on StackOverflow, but not one that can do so without prior knowledge of what columns are available.

```
  type value
1  rna     1
2  rna     2
3  rna     3
4  dna    20
5  dna    30


d<- data.frame (type=c("rna","rna","rna"), value = c(1,2,3) )
d2 <- data.frame (type=c("dna","dna"), value = c(20,30) )
df <- rbind (d,d2)


library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(type) %>%
    summarise_all(sum) %>%
    data.frame() %>%
    arrange(desc(value)) %>% # reorder row  
    select_(.dots = c("value","type") ) # reorder column
```

Comment: Can you provide an example what initial data would look like ("without some prior vector") and what the desired output would be? Not clear what you are trying to do from your question. Thanks :)

Comment: hi so the above example, the resulting df would produce a columns in this order: "type","value" without the last select line however if you look I have it order by the vector c("value","type") but would like to do so without it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort(names(.))` or `rev(sort(names(.)))` should work...

```
d<- data.frame (type=c("rna","rna","rna"), value = c(1,2,3) )
d2 <- data.frame (type=c("dna","dna"), value = c(20,30) )
df <- rbind (d,d2)


library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  arrange(desc(value)) %>% # reorder row  
  select(sort(names(.)))
```

Comment: just in case someone else needs this; there appears to be bug whereby certain packages will mess up  the select part of; to resolve this use dplyr::select instead of just select.  Here is a link to the bug. https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/643

Comment: That’s good to know / keep in mind, but I doubt that qualifies as a bug. If you load packages that have conflicting function names, R will map the most recently added one to the Global namespace, that’s by design.

Comment: yes agree; not a bug rather a too generalized nomenclature.